# What is the value of this limit? Does the value not exist or is this limit just indeterminate?

Tags: limits

Does $\;\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\dfrac2{5x|\sin x|}\;$ equal DNE (does not exist) or converge to $\,0$ ?

Although the $5x$ in the denominator approaches $\infty$, shouldn't the limit be DNE since at an arbitrary value of $x$, $|\sin x|$ will be $0.0000000000...1$ making the denominator not $\infty$ and the limit be something else other than $0$. Since the limit is not always $0$, must it not exist?

I had a conversation with my math teacher and he said it's definitely indeterminate as there may be a value that makes it not equal to $0$ but I have to prove that there are an infinite amount numbers that will make this not equal to $0$. If you can prove this, try proving it for natural numbers.

Comment: For this one it will be helpful to know the definition of limit, not just intuitive answers. Though there is also a fairly good intuitive explanation.

Comment: We don't usually say "equals DNE". Just "the limit does not exist" or "the limit is indeterminate". DNE is not a number or value, so it's misleading to say it's equal to anything. (We do sometimes say "equals infinity", which has the same issue, but is really defined to mean something other than equality.)

Comment: @OmSanan, are you still interested in a proof about the fact that there are infinitely many numbers $x_n$ for which the value of the function is not zero ?

Answer (score 2):

We will prove that there exists an increasing and unbounded above sequence $(x_n)$ of positive real numbers such that $\;f(x_n)\neq0\;$ where $$f(x)=\dfrac2{5x|\sin x|}\,.$$

**Proof:**

For any $\;n\in\Bbb N\,,\;$ let $\;g_n\!:\!\left[2\pi n,\dfrac{\pi}2\!+\!2\pi n\right]\to\Bbb R\;$ be the real function defined as follows :
$g_n(x)=x|\sin x|\quad$ for all $\;x\in\left[2\pi n,\dfrac{\pi}2\!+\!2\pi n\right].$

Since $\;g_n\;$ is a continuous function on its domain, $\;g_n(2\pi n)=0\;$ and $\;g_n\!\left(\dfrac{\pi}2\!+\!2\pi n\right)=\dfrac{\pi}2\!+\!2\pi n>1\,,\,$ by using the [Intermediate value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem) , we get that there exists $\;x_n\in\left]2\pi n,\dfrac{\pi}2\!+\!2\pi n\right[\;$ such that $\;g_n(x_n)=x_n|\sin x_n|=1\,.$

In this way we get a sequence $(x_n)$ of positive real numbers such that
$f(x_n)=\dfrac2{5x_n|\sin x_n|}=\dfrac25\neq0\,.$

Moreover, the sequence $(x_n)$ is increasing and unbounded above, indeed
$\color{blue}{2\pi n<x_n}<\dfrac{\pi}2\!+\!2\pi n<2\pi(n+1)\color{blue}{<x_{n+1}}\quad$ for any $\;n\in\Bbb N\,.$

Answer (score 1):

You are right in your effort or "mathematical guess": the limit does not exist because the function isn't defined in infinite points when $\;x\to\infty\;$, namely: all the points of the form $\;x=k\pi\;,\;\;k\in\Bbb N\;$ . This means that in any "neighborhood of infinity" (which formally means: for any $\;x>R\;,\;\;0<R\in\Bbb R$), there exist infinite points in that neighborhoodf for which the function does not even exist.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/143042/discussion-on-answer-by-donantonio-what-is-the-value-of-this-limit-does-the-val); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.